# SOAP request parameter in PHP, need 2 value with the same key in array

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

the XML structure that method needs two elements with same title. I use array to send parameters but dont know how to send two value with same key in array? if necessery SOAP 1.2 and PHP 5.x

Comment: Use numbered parameters instead.